# Phonegap + Facebook Connect

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cordova

I developed a phone gap application with [phonegap-build][1].

I wanted to implement the Facebook authentication. So, after some researches, I choosed https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4 plugin.

I configured my Facebook application and the server side. I compiled the phone gap application with build tools. And started to test it with [GenyMotion][2] and some Android virtual boxes.

So, everything worked. I could click on the Facebook button that send a request to the Facebook app that give me a response with the token and the ID and finally register or connect the user with the server side.

But when I install the application on Android or IOS9 smartphone, the Facebook connection doesn't work.

With Android, when I click on the Facebook button, the Facebook view appear asking me the right to connect my account with the application. But when I validate, the view disappears and nothing happens.

With IOS9, it's the same problem except that the plugin opens a safari view. I can validate but then the view also disappears.

Here is my function :

```
/** @method loginFacebook()
 * @private
 * Function to connect with facebook
*/
var loginFacebook = function () {
    facebookConnectPlugin.login( ["email"],
        function (response) {
          var id = JSON.stringify(response.authResponse.userID)
          navigator.notification.alert(
             'You are now connected',         
             loadMessages(),
             'Connection',                  
             'Thanks'  
          );
          checkUserConnection(id) //This is the server side
        }
)};

Thank you for your help

[1]: https://build.phonegap.com/
[2]: https://www.genymotion.com/
```